# Elasticbeantalk fails to deploy new docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I receive following error in the event log:

> [Instance: i-09368a0fa385b0525] Command failed on instance. An
>   unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].

At the moment, to work around it, I have to rebuild environment on every deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found the problem. It is because elastic beanstalk does not delete old image on new deployment. So it uses up all storage in the machine.

Regularly clean up docker images would fix the issue.